# How to check if remote image can be shown?

Tags: php, image, http-headers

Images from an remote server sometimes won't show on my site. They are broken. And getting `403 (Forbidden)` when checking in console.

So I wanna find out a way to pre-check if they are forbidden and then not show them, instead of a broken image.

So, my thought was to check http status with `get_headers()`. But it shows `200 OK` even for the broken images.

And then I found this solution after a google search, to use before `get_headers()`:

```
$default_opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Referer: http://www.fakesite.com/hotlink-check/",
  )
);

stream_context_set_default($default_opts);
```

But that doesn't work either. I have also tried `file_get_contents()` but that gave result for both non-broken and broken images.

So, how to check if a remote file has an 403 error?

**EDIT:**

Okay so, here are recent tests I've tried with:

```
$image = 'http://www.arabnews.com/sites/default/files/2018/02/28/1114386-582723106.jpg';
```

**Test 1:**

```
<?php
$default_opts = array(
'http' => array(
    'method' => "GET",
    'header' => "Referer: http://www.fakesite.com/hotlink-check/",
    'user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.1.6) Gecko/20091201 Firefox/3.5.6',
)
);
stream_context_set_default($default_opts);

$output = @get_headers($image, 1);

echo '<pre>'.print_r($output, true).'</pre>';
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [Date] => Wed, 28 Feb 2018 14:50:39 GMT
    [Content-Type] => image/jpeg
    [Content-Length] => 43896
    [Connection] => close
    [Set-Cookie] => __cfduid=d2a28d117e8a32d5755219bcd6e1892561519829439; expires=Thu, 28-Feb-19 14:50:39 GMT; path=/; domain=.arabnews.com; HttpOnly
    [X-Content-Type-Options] => nosniff
    [Last-Modified] => Tue, 27 Feb 2018 22:55:30 GMT
    [Cache-Control] => public, max-age=1209600
    [Expires] => Wed, 14 Mar 2018 14:50:39 GMT
    [X-Request-ID] => v-e065c0be-1c11-11e8-9caa-22000a6508a2
    [X-AH-Environment] => prod
    [X-Varnish] => 175579289 178981578
    [Via] => 1.1 varnish-v4
    [X-Cache] => HIT
    [X-Cache-Hits] => 8
    [CF-Cache-Status] => HIT
    [Accept-Ranges] => bytes
    [Server] => cloudflare
    [CF-RAY] => 3f44328fd0247179-ORD
)
```

**Test 2:**

```
<?php
function get_response_code($url) {

    @file_get_contents($url);
    list($version, $status, $text) = explode(' ', $http_response_header[0], 3);

    return $status;
}

$output = get_response_code($image);

echo '<pre>'.print_r($output, true).'</pre>';
?>
```

Output:

```
200
```

**Test 3:**

```
<?php
$output = getimagesize($image);

echo '<pre>'.print_r($output, true).'</pre>';
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 650
    [1] => 395
    [2] => 2
    [3] => width="650" height="395"
    [bits] => 8
    [channels] => 3
    [mime] => image/jpeg
)
```

Comment: The reason why the remote server refuses to serve the file may be different between your server and the browser. You probably want to attach a Javascript event handler for when an image fails to load and replace it or hide it then.

Comment: Try to set `user_agent` for http stream context

Comment: @Dan Miller Okay, like, what user agent? What should the value be?

Comment: Something like `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.1.6) Gecko/20091201 Firefox/3.5.6` just to emulate users browser, Im not sure if it will work

Comment: Dan Miller: Didn't worked. See my edited post above.

Answer (score 0):

Check the image size. This is the easiest and most effective solution:

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("www.url.com/img.jpg");
```

If especially the first two; `$width` and `$height` are set, and `$type` is a valid value you are good to go.

**And I would display them in this case.**

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I've tried that as well. But sadly not working. Get correct image size and type but the image is still broken and return 403 error.

Comment: buckyBadger: Gave `200` :/

Comment: Can you post an example file url ?